# Pandoc , how to attach files from markdown to docx

Tags: pandoc

I write my notes in markdown with some links to local files

```
## Heading1
sometext 
[local file](path to loacl file)
```

Is there a way to attach this file "local file" while converting from markdown to docx ?

so that when sharing the file it include the local file as an attachment

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: added extra clarification